# Remove all text except specific text and value Regex

Tags: php, regex, wordpress

I have a problem with RegEX. I have output like this.

```
Number of rooms 
2
Price
120000
Square in meter
60
```

I’m trying to achieve this: I want remove all text except “Number of rooms 2” My value “2”  changes. So far I have expression like this:

```
<?php 
   $str = get_field('all'); 
   preg_match('/ Number of rooms \s*(\d+)/' , $str, $matches); 
   echo $matches[1]; 
?>
```

Comment: Why are you demanding for a space character before and after `Number of rooms`?

Answer (score 2):

Remove the preceding space before the `Number` word :

```
preg_match('/Number of rooms \s*(\d+)/' , $str, $matches);
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the Space before `Number` and after `rooms` in your regex:

```
$str = 'Number of rooms 
2
Price
120000
Square in meter
60'; 
preg_match('/Number of rooms\s*(\d+)/' , $str, $matches); 
print_r($matches);
```

**output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Number of rooms 
2
    [1] => 2
)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try it this way:

```
$str = get_field('all'); 
$str_array = explode("\n",$str); 
$new_str=$str_array[0]." ".$str_array[1]; 
echo $new_str;
```

Comment: Your code will output "Number of rooms", not "2" as requested. Also it's not a good method to to use anyways. You could read up on implode() function it will come handy for you some day.

Comment: didn't he request "Number of rooms 2". i think the result will be it. yes ofcourse we can also use implode

Comment: And what about: "The number of rooms is\n2"?

Comment: sorry did not realized that he has extra space after rooms. the answer already fixed

Comment: Looking at the code in the question he to $matches[1] which is the capture, i.e. "2"

Answer (score 0):

As the others has said it's the space. You can solve it with removing the space or make it optional with `*`.

I would advise to use regex options `im` also as it will be case insensitive and treat the string as multilined.

```
preg_match('/number of rooms\s*(\d+)/im', $str, $m);
var_dump($m);
```